# Does the ring on "gold ring" Nikkor lenses contain any real gold?

Tags: nikon

I noticed that the "gold ring" on certain Tokina and older Sigma lenses is actually a thin strip of gold-colored sticker.

I just picked up my gold ring Nikkor and noticed that the "gold ring" seems like something solid - it looks like a thin strip of metal curved into the shape of a ring. There's a visible gap in the ring at the back of the lens.

This made me wonder: Does the ring on "gold ring" Nikkor lenses contain any real gold?

Comment: vtc b/c This is a question about decorative materials in lenses that is unrelated to photography.

Comment: There's unlikely any gold in the decorative ring.  You can learn to identify unknown materials in chemistry classes.

Answer (score 2):

The gold ring is there to indicate the quality of the glass and design of the lens, it's not there to add value in and of itself. Why would Nikon use real gold? It's expensive and wasteful - increasing manufacturing costs for no good reason. These are utilitarian lenses, not jewellery.

Comment: *These are utilitarian lenses, not jewelry* Leica wants a word with you.

Comment: It's more the case that many who buy Leica cameras would like a word with osullic.